# Compression: Saving JPEG image at specified bit rate in Java / Scala

Tags: java, scala, compression, jpeg

I'm interested in saving a JPEG image so that I can specify the total number of bits used to encode all the pixels in the compressed form. For example, if I have a 4 channel image of size 1024 x 1024, encoding the bits without compression would take 4 * 8 * 1024 * 1024 bits. Using compression, significantly fewer bits might be used. I want to specify the number of bits in the compressed form.

An iterative solution would be binary search on the JPEG compression quality parameter. I'm hoping for a direct solution in Java or Scala.

Comment: Not going to happen, because until the full compression is actually attempted you won't know what the outcome will be (such is the nature of lossy compression). You can roughly estimate it, but there is no "make it x bytes big" call. Binary search is about as good as you're going to do.

Comment: @Chris That's also my opinion. I think you should transform your comment into an answer.

Comment: @paradigmatic as a rule of mine, I don't post something as an answer unless I'm actually answering the question asked. In this case the OP explicitly stated that something better than binary search was desirable, so I don't think I'm really answering anything.

Comment: @Chris That's not the nature of lossy compression. There are lossy compression schemes which make it pretty straight to estimate the outcome size - like a bit-depth reduction. Also there are lossless compression schemes which don't allow estimating the resulting size (like zip and thus png). But I think it's true that every decent compression has a varying compression ratio depending on the content (with fixed quality). Though some compressors allow to specify a target bitrate, which they try to meet by varying the quality.

Answer (score 0):

As @Chris said, there are no shortcuts with JPEG. However - and I realise that this is a long shot - you can specify the compression rate directly if you are willing to use JPEG2000 instead of JPEG. If you look at the [Encoder](http://code.google.com/p/jj2000/source/browse/trunk/src/main/java/jj2000/j2k/encoder/Encoder.java) class in this [JJ2000 library](http://code.google.com/p/jj2000/), you'll see how to fix the bitrate of the encoded image.

Unfortunately, as JPEG2000 support is nowhere near as widespread as JPEG, I fear this may not be much use to you.